# How to generate JSON in specific format

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to get something like

```
{ 
    'genre' : [{
        'type' : 'Comedy'
        }, {
         'type' : 'Action'
        }, {
        'type' : 'Romance'
        }]
}
```

I tried putting setting a PHP array like

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $m['genre']['type'][] = $row['genre'];
}
```

But it comes like  `"genre": {"type":["Thriller","Drama"]}`.

How do I rewrite the PHP code to get the required JSON string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need only apply a little logic!

```
$m = Array('genre' => Array());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   $m['genre'][] = Array('type' => $row['genre']);
}

print json_encode($m);
```